# Trying to find the lowest possible value for $x^2+y^2$ while still holding true for another equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I have two variables $x,y$, and I want them to in this equation $x^2+y^2$ be the lowest possible values while still holding true to this equation $(x+7) ^2+(y+2) ^2+(y-3) =51$. How could I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Draw the circle $(x+7) ^2+(y+2) ^2+(y-3) =51$ and locate the point on it which is nearest to the origin.